# fix corrupt file with same inode than an other (linux, ntfs)

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, file-corruption, inode

While copying thousands of images on a new disk with a pi (raspbian), rsync stopped with an error, impossible to move temp file to correct file name.

The real file name actually exists but has the same inode than an other file in the same folder (same partition) :

```
$ stat -c '%i' ./2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-18-23.JPG ./2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-20-09.JPG
26768 
26768
```

The first file cannot be removed :

```
$ rm ./2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-18-23.JPG
rm: impossible de supprimer './2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-18-23.JPG': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

(impossible to remove xxx no file or folder of this type)

But the second can but then `ls` on the first file gives a different error message :

```
$ ls  -alh ./2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-18-23.JPG
ls: impossible d'accéder à './2021-04-12/image_2021-04-12_18-18-23.JPG': Erreur d'entrée/sortie
```

(i/o error)

The error might have been generated by several rsync running on the same folder at the same time but how could I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not really fix the filesystem. Hooking it to a Windows machine only led to lost time and patience.

Copying everything to an other disk, formatting and copying back worked just fine.